# MySQL set the result of a query = to a column binary

Tags: mysql, select

I want to create a new variable/column in my dataset that signifies the presence or lack there of a data mining query.

I thought it would be:

```
SELECT * INTO @variable1 
FROM dataset 
WHERE CONTENTS RLIKE '[[:<:]]foo[[:>:]]' 
OR CONTENTS RLIKE '[[:<:]]example[[:>:]]'
```

However I get the error:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s).

I think I somehow need to say SELECT as a binary (not as *), but not sure how to do this.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to put all columns returned by `select *` into just one variable `@variable1` which obviously makes no sense.

Comment: Looks like you need `SELECT *, ( {subquery here with if/then statement to determine the boolean } ) AS 'ColumnName' FROM dataset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things in order to accomplish this.

First, you must alter `dataset` to have a column for your result:

```
ALTER TABLE dataset ADD CONTENTS_FLAG tinyint(1) NOT NULL default 0.
```

Now, you need to update the new `dataset` column with the results of your query:

```
UPDATE dataset SET CONTENTS_FLAG = 1 
WHERE CONTENTS RLIKE '[[:<:]]foo[[:>:]]' 
OR CONTENTS RLIKE '[[:<:]]example[[:>:]]'
```